# Graph Theory—stereographic projection

Tags: graph-theory, stereographic-projections

> **Context**: I'm in an introductory Graph Theory class, and my professor decided
> to discuss stereographic projection for some reason unknown to me. It's a topic
> that's not even mentioned in the textbook we're using.
>
> **QUESTION**: Express the stereographic projection algebraically given the following definitions:
> ***X*** : the sphere *x*$^2$ + *y*$^2$ + *z*$^2$ = 1, 
> ***N*** : the north pole (0, 0, 1), 
> ${\rm I\!R}$$^2$ : the plane *z* = 0, 
> ***Y*** : ***X*** — {***N***}, and 
> $\phi$ : the function ***Y***$\rightarrow$${\rm I\!R}$$^2$ 
>  
> That is, find $\alpha$(*x, y, z*) and $\beta$*(x, y, z*) where $\phi$(***P***) = ($\alpha$, $\beta$). 
> He also gave us a **hint**: Write the equation of the line through ***N*** and ***P*** (the point on the sphere) and intersect it with the plane *z* = 0.

**Thoughts in my head**: What??? This seems a little intimidating since (1) there are several parts, (2) because it isn't even explained in the textbook, and (3) because my professor isn't the best communicator/teacher. So I'm having trouble where to start. I apologize if this is a bad question, but really my brain isn't producing very much help either.

Comment: Stereographic projection and graph theory are related! See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024598/a-planar-graph-can-be-embedded-in-the-plane-in-such-a-way-that-any-vertex-is-on/

Comment: @Robert I realize this, but unfortunately the question in the link you provided doesn't quite help me with the question that I have posed here

Comment: After googling I found http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~boyang/2220%20s2017/math2220_notes/notes_sec_2.1.pdf

Comment: I guess, your confusion arises because part of the exercise is written only in the hint. Namely, that $\phi$ is defined by using straight lines from the north pole.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P=(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in Y$, i.e. it's a point on the sphere, distinct to the north pole $N$.

Then $\phi(P)$ is *defined as* the intersection of line $NP$ with the $x, y$-plane $H$ (which has equation $z=0$).
Note that $H$ is *identified with* $\Bbb R^2$ in the exercise by regarding $(x,y,0)\in H$ as $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$.

Now the line $NP$ consists of points $N+t(P-N)$ with $t\in\Bbb R$, that is, of points
$$(0,0,1)+t(x_0,y_0,z_0-1)\ =\ (tx_0,\,ty_0,\,1+t(z_0-1))$$
You can obtain the unique $t$ for which this point is on $H$, by solving $1+t(z_0-1)=0$, and then substitute it into $\phi(P) =(tx_0,ty_0) $.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help show the mapping:

[image]